# Convert PHP Array to Json. Using Code-igniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I Convert PHP Array To JSON Success But My target not full fill.

**My out put is:**

```
{"id":"145","logid":"","name":"asasa"}{"id":"144","logid":"","name":"qwsqwswq"}{"id":"145","logid":"","name":"asasa"}{"id":"144","logid":"","name":"qwsqwswq"}
```

My Requirement :

```
[{"id":"145","logid":"","name":"asasa"}{"id":"144","logid":"","name":"qwsqwswq"}{"id":"145","logid":"","name":"asasa"}{"id":"144","logid":"","name":"qwsqwswq"}]
```

Here my code:-

```
if ($AdminRecord) {

                    foreach($AdminRecord->result() as $results)
                    {
                      echo json_encode($results);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are outputting every row, instead try this:

```
$resultSet = Array();
if($AdminRecord){
    foreach($AdminRecord->result() as $result) {
       $resultSet[] = $result;
    }
}
echo json_encode($resultSet);
```

Comment: That's Great R Singh, धन्यवाद

Comment: @AnshuPratapYadav , please change this to Accepted answer if it solved your query.

Comment: It's Working well Thanks R Singh.@